# How to create XML file without external libraries in Java 9?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-9

> How to create `XML` file **without external libraries** in Java 9?

Currently I am using `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` and `javax.xml.bind.Marshaller` classes to do that, but on Java 9 these classes does not exist any more. So while using Java 9 I am getting an exception:  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext`.
I can create `XML` file with lower Java version, but I need it will be compatible and for Java 9.

---

The way I am creating XML file right now is:

#### 1. Create XML element class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Places {

    private List<Athlete> athletes;

    public List<Athlete> getAthletes() {
        return athletes;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setAthletes(List<Athlete> athletes) {
        this.athletes = athletes;
    }
}
```

#### 2. Create XML file

```
List<Athlete> athletes = new ArrayList<>();
Places places = new Places();
places.setAthletes(athletes);    
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Places.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(places, new File(outputPath);
marshaller.marshal(places, System.out);
```

---

I hope someone encountered with this problem already and know how to solve it.

P.S.: *I have searched for the answer of this question but doesn't found anything, so it shouldn't be a duplicated question.*
*As I mention* ***I have to use only Java internal libraries for that.***

Comment: *I have to use only Java internal libraries for that.* - why?

Comment: Did you read the API docs? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml-summary.html

Comment: @lexicore Because of the task the company gave my where I am applying for the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these libraries in Java 9, but you need to require the module that contains them. Ensure that your `module-info.java` has a requirement for the `java.xml` module:

```
module myModule {
    requires java.xml;
}
```

As you require more functionality from the JAXB modules, you will need to add more `requires` statements in your `module-info.java` file. For example, your `module-info.java` file may look more like the following when you are done:

```
module myModule {
   java.xml
   java.xml.bind
   java.xml.ws
   java.xml.ws.annotation
}
```

For more information, see [How to resolve `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException` in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j).